# Request Transaction-List from Paypal

Tags: java, rest, http, paypal

I try to request a transaction list from paypal but I allways get HTTP-Code 400

```
public void getTransactionList(String accessToken)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(
            "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions"
                + "?start_date=2018-01-01T00:00:00Z&end_date=2018-04-01T00:00:00Z"
                + "&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1");

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en_US");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw new ActionException(e);
    }
}
```

The Exception is

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2018-01-01T00:00:00-000&end_date=2018-04-02T00:00:00-000&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at de.crefo.workflow.paypal.http.HttpRestClient.getTransactionList(HttpRestClient.java:42)
at de.crefo.workflow.paypal.http.HttpRestClient.main(HttpRestClient.java:112)
```

The Access-Token request, I do in a similar way, is working perfectly fine and gives me a valid token.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT. Changed dateformat in URL, see comments.

Comment: Why are you sending `Content-Type` in a `GET` request?

Comment: Because it's in the curl example from paypal:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/sync/#list-transactions

But even without it, I get the same Exception

Comment: @Eardy : Is the start time and end time formats are correct? start_date=2018-01-01T00:00:00-000&end_date=2018-04-02T00:00:00-000 I think it should be 

start_date=2018-01-01T00:00:00-00:00&end_date=2018-04-02T00:00:00-00:00

Comment: I think the issue is with the query parameters that you are sending in the request. Can you reverify from Paypal API docs that you are sending correct query parameters?

Comment: You were right, the dateformat has to be different (2018-01-01T00:00:00Z) but I still get the same exception

Comment: At the end, I found out that's not possible to request transations without transactionId even if the API-documentation doesn't say so. I switcht to the NVP API and now everything ist working for me